# Tensorflow Retrain an Image Classifier

Tags: tensorflow, go, deep-learning

I just followed the documentation [here Image Retraining](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining)

In step **Using the Retrained Model** I have a very correct estimate

```
python label_image.py --graph=graph.pb --labels=labels.pb --input_layer=Placeholder --output_layer=final_result --image=../color/blue/blue25.jpg
2018-09-30 10:57:53.153552: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
blue 0.9326643
red 0.06733578
```

But if i try to use in this code :

[tf-classifier by hybridgroup/gocv](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/blob/3f4d73bc6a6e20e4880c0ea208f3e80880e1c725/cmd/tf-classifier/main.go)

i have a error :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/opencv-20180704-99354-1kt9ska/opencv-3.4.2/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:2270: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) Requested blob "input" not found in function 'setInput'
```

But if I use Tensorflow "Inception" model it works.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find the answer by any chance ?